# Alert my application when email unsubscribe happens

Tags: marketing-cloud, email

In my salesforce marketing cloud application, when a user clicks unsubscribe I want it to alert my application so I know to update consent in my application.

I don't see how to do this? I opened a support case and was told this was not functionality that was available.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not an MC expert but if you can't get MC to push an alert, you should be able to get your application to pull in the subscription preferences on a nightly bases or something. If that's not possible then I don't see any way for you to get what you need.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such functionality, that lets you listen for unsubscribes. However you have a few possibilities for a workaround, including the following:

1. If you use a custom Unsubscribe-Page, you can add an API-Call to your application from there and therefore you have an immediate connection.
2. Build a scheduled job in your application that regularly retrieves unsubscribes.
3. Build an automation in Marketing Cloud that regularly exports all the unsubscribes and pushes it to your system (via a file to an ftp or via a script activity / api call to your application).

**Helpful resources:**

- [Server-Side JavaScript](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_serverSideJavaScript.htm)
- [Retrieve the SubscriberStatusEvent](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/retrieving_the_subscriberstatusevent.htm)
- [Automation Studio Activities](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_using_automation_studio_activities.htm&type=5)

Answer (score 0):

It seems possible, but will require development.

Assuming your application has an API endpoint where MC could push the consent update, you would need to make an automation that does the following:

- uses SQL query to get a list of unsubscribed customers from the Unsubscribe data view from a specific time range (depends how often do you want to update your consents)
- write contents to a data extension
- use the [Script activity](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_create_a_script_activity_1.htm&type=5) and write server-side JavaScript that pushes the updates to your API endpoint